# What is the tiny switch on AMD Radeon graphics cards?

Tags: gpu, amd-radeon

I have an R9 290 and a R7970. Both have a tiny switch next to the CrossFire connections. What is its purpose and which position means what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of mixed(wrong) information about it(and since I don't have any of these cards it's hard to test),

*I'll try my best here.*

***Quick short***:

> *One of them is the stock and the second is unprotected for flashing or voltage tweaks for overclocking.*
>
> There are two bioses so if you mess one up from flashing a higher voltage or higher clock you can switch to the second one.

*Sure this is the default settings of general graphic cards roughly speaking.*

*In another graphic cards like [AMD Radeon R9-290](https://www.guru3d.com/articles-pages/radeon-r9-290-review-benchmarks,15.html) seems to do a different thing.*

and more info, for the [R7970](https://youtu.be/1eU8QAEAcY4?t=433) in this YouTube video.

---

***Edit: So if you want to overclock the graphic adapters and for some reason it did not worked after while, you would change that little switch back to the normal 'default clock' which is a smart idea since once upon a time I overclocked a AMD before then after I got black screen slow system and Windows would not work anymore. Only option I'd to reinstall Windows and the drivers all again to get things back to the normal because the machine would either boot!***

You should never touch these switches and once you change it only have effect after reboot.

..and if you need to change them by urgency or mistake you don't need to restart for that(but remember effects only after boot).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. (When I tried Googling the question, it just came up with about of articles about switchable graphics!)